# Macro added PrevSheet function returns #NAME error

Tags: excel, vba

I added a simple Previous Sheet macro to file and it worked normally, until it started to return #NAME error, and i can't figure out why.

I meant to use it with named single cell ranges which are consistent across the workbook, I'd used it successfully before naming the ranges and didn't think it would have any impact on the fuction. After naming the ranges though it no longer works, not even for regular non named ranges.

I have tested this by creating a new workbook, filling some sheets and trying it out, and it still returns a `#NAME` error. When i evaluate the function, the error appears at the very first step: recognizing the function. However, when i type into the formula bar, the programs offers me the formula normally.

I have also tried referring to the named cells by its cell, and even adding the worksheet name before the cell (eg "`prevsheet(previoussheetname!a1)`, or `prevsheet(thissheetname!a1)`). I have even, in a last ditch effort, tried adding double quotes before the cell name.

For full disclosure, i have also another macro subroutine that uses references to previous and next sheets, but as it wouldnt recognize the function itself (which should have been an early sign), it makes use of relative referencing  (ie `activesheet(index - 1`, `activesheet(index + 1)`). At the time i didn't think it would mess up the function, but as i grow ever more desperate and confused, maybe thats a possibility.

the `PrevSheet()` code i was using:

```
Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range)

    Dim xIndex As Long

    Application.Volatile

    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index

    If xIndex > 1 Then _
        PrevSheet = Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address)

End Function
```

And as it is now, as suggested by Chris Neilsen

Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range) As Variant

```
Application.Volatile

PrevSheet = RCell.Worksheet.Previous.Range(RCell.Address).Value
```

End Function

As suggested by Chris Neilsen i have edited the named ranges to look like this:

`!(nothing)$column$row` with its scope set to `Workbook`

[image: name manager]

The named range is not available at the range browser. 
[image: range browser]

Only cell B1 is named. It is called "name"
[image: sheet1]

PrevSheet() does not work with either range. 
[image: sheet2]

Macros are enabled

[image: macros are enabled]

Anyone with a better understanding of vba, macros and excel can tell me why this is happening and how do i fix it so it returns the value of the specified cell in the first sheet to the left of sheet the function is typed in? (ie, in sheet4, `=prevsheet(A1)` will return the value of cell A1 in sheet3)

I hope my question is clearer now!

Comment: It is unclear what you want the function to return...........the **name of the previous worksheet** or or the **value of the cells** in the previous worksheet or **what**  ??

Comment: `#NAME` indicates the UDF `PrevSheet` is not found, from current workbook or any addins. Your UDF should return Range. If macro was enabled then this UDF function should show and not give you *#NAME* error.

Comment: Your issues may be related to how you have defined your Named Ranges.  Please update your Q with full details of your Names

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work **if it is placed in a Standard Module**:

```
Public Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range) As Variant
    Dim xIndex As Long
    Application.Volatile

    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index
    MsgBox xIndex
    If xIndex > 1 Then
        PrevSheet = Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address)
    End If
End Function
```

[image]

For example, in the worksheet:

[image]

I have assigned cell **A7** the Name *junk* and the 666 is the value in the previous sheet's cell **A7**.

Comment: Can you help me with this question? I tried everything I knew but could not solve. stackoverflow.com/q/56207459/8631622 @Gary's Student

Answer (score 0):

This will work, if you define your Named Ranges correctly.  There are several ways this can be done, but here's one that is IMO simplest.

Since you say *...use it with named single cell ranges which are consistent across the workbook.* you can create a single Named Range, Workbook scope, that will refer to  a cell (or cells) on the sheet which references the name.

Lets say you want to refer to cell `A1`.  In Name Manager, create a Name, lets say `YourNamedRange` workbook scope, Reference `=!$A$1`  (Note the `!` without a sheet reference).

When you add a formula to a sheet (eg `=YourNamedRange`) it will refer to cell `A1` *on the sheet containing the formula*.

Applying it to your UDF, just use `=PrevSheet(YourNamedRange)`

[image]

Your UDF works (mostly) as is, but will fail if a different Workbook is active.  To fix that, use

```
Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range)
    Dim xIndex As Long
    Application.Volatile
    xIndex = RCell.Worksheet.Index
    If xIndex > 1 Then
        With RCell.Worksheet.Parent 'The workbook containing RCell
            PrevSheet = .Worksheets(xIndex - 1).Range(RCell.Address)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

There is also a `Worksheet`Property called `Previous` that does much the same thing, so you can refactor as

```
Function PrevSheet(RCell As Range) As Variant
    Application.Volatile
    PrevSheet = RCell.Worksheet.Previous.Range(RCell.Address).Value
End Function
```

Comment: Ive amended the code and respecified the ranges as you suggested, and it still doesn't work? Let me show you  <br/>
![the name manager](https://imgur.com/1nEN0YJ)  <br/>

it doesnt show me the names on the dropdown  <br/>

![it doesnt show me the names on the dropdown bar](https://imgur.com/gsWtPPs).  <br/>

sheet 1. the range bar doesnt display the named range when selected  <br/>

![sheet1](https://imgur.com/9aHULD8).  <br/>

!sheet 2. the prevsheet function doesnt work either way  [sheet2](https://imgur.com/bDJtbKQ).

Comment: @Flamingo for some reason that style of Name doesn't show in the dropdown.  To fix the `#Name?` issue, change the name of your Module to something other than `PrevSheet`  (making it the same as the UDF has created a conflict)

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. In my case I uninstalled KuTools. and upon reponening the excel file containing =prevsheet, all is fixed!